# Python: matching strings against pattern strings with number, string, and date placeholders with good error catching

Tags: python, regex, string, date

I want to write a function:

```
match_string(input, pattern, valid_words, date_format)
```

`input` is a normal string. `pattern` is a string that has placeholders for numbers, words, and dates. For example, "# is a number ## is a string and ### is a date". Here I've used #, #, and ### to denote number, string, and date placeholders respectively, but I'm not bound to any particular representation of placeholder.

`match_string` should return true if `input` "matches" the pattern; that is, if it has numbers where there are numbers placeholders, words where there are words placeholders *and* the word is in the given valid_words list, and dates where there are date placeholders and the date is in the given `date_format`.

And finally I need match_string to return detailed error information; if `input` doesn't match, and it was one of the placeholders, it should say "not a number", "not in words list", or "not a date". If it doesn't match on normal parts of pattern, it should just error or return False

This is a lot to ask :) but question is how to implement `match_string`. I see regular expressions and string formats and custom error definitions should help me, but I'm having trouble pulling it all together. I hope this question can help others by showing a flexible use of regex in python.

Examples:

```
> match_string('1 is a number foo is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', [foo], '%m-%d-%y')
True

> match_string('foo is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', [foo], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: number expected for 'foo'

> match_string('1 is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', [foo], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: invalid word: bar

> match_string('1 is a number foo is a string January is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', [foo], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: invalid date format January
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now we know what you want and what you need. But what is your question?

Comment: how should `match_string` be implemented?

Comment: You should at least include a few example inputs and expected outputs for the different outputs.

Comment: Post you best try, even if you feel it's far from it.  Additionally, post test cases and positive and negative responses (what your program should do in each case, and what not).

Comment: What do you want to happen if the input fails to match in multiple ways. That is, if your pattern is `'# ## ###'` and you get an input of `'x'`, (and `x` is not a valid word), it fails all parts of the pattern.

Comment: @MarioRossi added some examples, hope its more clear.

Comment: @Blckknght for ambiguous failures it can return a generic failure error

Comment: And yet again: Which specific problem do you face implementing this method?

Comment: It would be much easier if you didn't need specific errors. You could probably get a single regex that would work, but it wouldn't tell you what specifically failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be more efficient to either manipulate the string directly, or just modify a single regex pattern. Unfortunately the later will only return true or false.

Anyway I created a script as requested, It will accept 31 days in every month though, but it should be fairly easy to add more limitations.

```
from re import sub, match

def match_string(input, pattern, valid_words, date_format):
    errors = []

    # makes sure that input and pattern are compatible
    regex_pattern = sub(r'#{1,3}', '(.+?)', pattern)
    if not match(regex_pattern, input):
        return 'Error: Input doesn\'t match pattern!'   

    # converts the data_format to a regex
    date_regex = sub(r'%d', '(?P<day>\d+)', date_format)
    date_regex = sub(r'%m', '(?P<month>\d+)', date_regex)
    date_regex = sub(r'%y', '(?P<year>\d+)', date_regex)

    # extracts the dates
    regex_pattern = sub(r'###', '(.+?)', pattern)
    regex_pattern = sub(r'##', '(?:.+?)', regex_pattern)
    regex_pattern = sub(r'#', '(?:.+?)', regex_pattern)
    for date in match(regex_pattern, input).groups():
        m = match(date_regex, date)
        if not m:
            errors.append('Error: %s is not a valid date!' % date)
        else:
            if int(m.group('day')) < 1 or 31 < int(m.group('day')):
                errors.append('Error: %s is not a valid day!' % m.group('day'))
            if int(m.group('month')) < 1 or 12 < int(m.group('month')):
                errors.append('Error: %s is not a valid month!' % m.group('month'))

    # extracts the generic words
    regex_pattern = sub(r'###', '(?:.+?)', pattern)
    regex_pattern = sub(r'##', '(.+?)', regex_pattern)
    regex_pattern = sub(r'#', '(?:.+?)', regex_pattern)
    for word in match(regex_pattern, input).groups():
        if not word.strip() in valid_words:
            errors.append('Error: %s is not a valid word!' % word)

    # extracts the numbers
    regex_pattern = sub(r'###', '(?:.+?)', pattern)
    regex_pattern = sub(r'##', '(?:.+?)', regex_pattern)
    regex_pattern = sub(r'#', '(.+?)', regex_pattern)
    for number in match(regex_pattern, input).groups():
        if not match(r'\d+', number):
            errors.append('Error: %s is not a valid number!' % number)

    if len(errors) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return '\n'.join(errors)

print match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 12-1-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
print
print match_string('1 is a number foo is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
print
print match_string('foo is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
print
print match_string('1 is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
print
print match_string('1 is a number foo is a string January is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
```

Produces the result:

```
True

True

Error: bar is not a valid word!
Error: foo is not a valid number!

Error: bar is not a valid word!

Error: January is not a valid date!
```

As you can see your second example has two errors, not one.

**EDIT:**

I remade the program without using regex. It should be more efficient. It may seem that it only traverses the input once, but it still reads some characters multiply times with the startswith() method.

This version returns immediately when an error is detected. Hence it will only detect the first error for each input.

```
def match_string(input, pattern, valid_words, date_format):
    print '\n> match_string(\'%s\', \'%s\', %s, \'%s\')' % (input, pattern, valid_words, date_format)

    digits = '0123456789'
    inputIndex = 0
    patternIndex = 0

    while inputIndex < len(input) and patternIndex < len(pattern):
        if pattern[patternIndex] == '#':
            patternIndex += 1
            if pattern[patternIndex] == '#':
                patternIndex += 1
                if pattern[patternIndex] == '#':

                    # validate date
                    date_formatIndex = 0
                    while inputIndex < len(input) and date_formatIndex < len(date_format):

                        if input[inputIndex] == date_format[date_formatIndex]:
                            inputIndex += 1
                            date_formatIndex += 1

                        elif input[inputIndex] in digits:

                            startIndex = inputIndex
                            while inputIndex < len(input) and input[inputIndex] in digits:
                                inputIndex += 1
                            number = int(input[startIndex:inputIndex])

                            if date_format[date_formatIndex:].startswith('%y'):
                                placeholder = True
                            elif date_format[date_formatIndex:].startswith('%m'):
                                if number < 1 or 12 < number:
                                    return 'Error: expected a month between 1 and 12\n input   %d -> "...%s"\n pattern %d -> "...%s"\n date format %d -> "...%s"' % (startIndex, input[startIndex:], patternIndex - 2, pattern[patternIndex - 2:], date_formatIndex, date_format[date_formatIndex:])   

                            elif date_format[date_formatIndex:].startswith('%d'):
                                if number < 1 or 31 < number:
                                    return 'Error: expected a day between 1 and 31\n input   %d -> "...%s"\n pattern %d -> "...%s"\n date format %d -> "...%s"' % (startIndex, input[startIndex:], patternIndex - 2, pattern[patternIndex - 2:], date_formatIndex, date_format[date_formatIndex:])   

                            else:
                                return 'Error: input doesn\'t match date format\n input   %d -> "...%s"\n pattern %d -> "...%s"\n date format %d -> "...%s"' % (startIndex, input[startIndex:], patternIndex - 2, pattern[patternIndex - 2:], date_formatIndex, date_format[date_formatIndex:])   

                            date_formatIndex += 2

                        else:
                            return 'Error: input doesn\'t match date format\n input   %d -> "...%s"\n pattern %d -> "...%s"\n date format %d -> "...%s"' % (inputIndex, input[inputIndex:], patternIndex - 2, pattern[patternIndex - 2:], date_formatIndex, date_format[date_formatIndex:])   

                    patternIndex += 1

                else:
                    # validate word
                    valid = False
                    for word in valid_words:
                        if input[inputIndex:].startswith(word):
                            valid = True
                            inputIndex += len(word)
                            break
                    if not valid:
                        return 'Error: expected a valid word\n input   %d -> "...%s"\n pattern %d -> "...%s"' % (inputIndex, input[inputIndex:], patternIndex - 2, pattern[patternIndex - 2:])                    

            else:
                # validate number
                if not input[inputIndex] in digits:
                    return 'Error: expected a number\n input   %d -> "...%s"\n pattern %d -> "...%s"' % (inputIndex, input[inputIndex:], patternIndex - 1, pattern[patternIndex - 1:])
                while inputIndex < len(input) and input[inputIndex] in digits:
                    inputIndex += 1

        elif input[inputIndex] != pattern[patternIndex]:
            return 'Error: input and pattern do not match\n input   %d -> "...%s"\n pattern %d -> "...%s"' % (inputIndex, input[inputIndex:], patternIndex, pattern[patternIndex:])
        else:
            inputIndex += 1            
            patternIndex += 1
    return True

print match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 12-1-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
print match_string('1 is a number foo is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
print match_string('foo is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
print match_string('1 is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
print match_string('1 is a number foo is a string January is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
print match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 15-1-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
print match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 08-42-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
print match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 08;4;2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
print match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 08-4-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '~%m-%d-%y')
```

Produces the result (I added some more tests):

```
> match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 12-1-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
True

> match_string('1 is a number foo is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
True

> match_string('foo is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: expected a number
 input   0 -> "...foo is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date"
 pattern 0 -> "...# is a number ## is a string ### is a date"

> match_string('1 is a number bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: expected a valid word
 input   14 -> "...bar is a string 12-1-2013 is a date"
 pattern 14 -> "...## is a string ### is a date"

> match_string('1 is a number foo is a string January is a date', '# is a number ## is a string ### is a date', ['foo'], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: input doesn't match date format
 input   30 -> "...January is a date"
 pattern 29 -> "...### is a date"
 date format 0 -> "...%m-%d-%y"

> match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 15-1-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: expected a month between 1 and 12
 input   44 -> "...15-1-2013 is a date"
 pattern 42 -> "...### is a date"
 date format 0 -> "...%m-%d-%y"

> match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 08-42-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: expected a day between 1 and 31
 input   47 -> "...42-2013 is a date"
 pattern 42 -> "...### is a date"
 date format 3 -> "...%d-%y"

> match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 08;4;2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '%m-%d-%y')
Error: input doesn't match date format
 input   46 -> "...;4;2013 is a date"
 pattern 42 -> "...### is a date"
 date format 2 -> "...-%d-%y"

> match_string('1 and 2 are numbers foo and bar are strings 08-4-2013 is a date', '# and # are numbers ## and ## are strings ### is a date', ['foo', 'bar'], '~%m-%d-%y')
Error: input doesn't match date format
 input   44 -> "...08-4-2013 is a date"
 pattern 42 -> "...### is a date"
 date format 0 -> "...~%m-%d-%y"
```

Comment: Great @Akinakes! I implemented a variation of this. Minor question. is sub() necessary for the replacement of '#'s with regexes? Can we just use replace()?

Comment: String manipulation is preferable to regex if possible so replace() is better than sub() in this case. I didn't consider it when I wrote the code. Note that it's even quicker to implement your own replace method that manipulates the string directly and thus only has to traverse the string once and not several times like in my code.

Comment: @Neil I remade the program without regex for comparison. The later version should be quicker.